# Is the Fibonacci crocodile still being displayed at the Centre Pompidou in Paris?

Tags: paris, museums, geek-travel, artworks

In 2004 I visited the Centre Pompidou in Paris and back then I really liked the Fibonacci crocodile. Being a fan of numbers, I like art where numbers play a crucial role. I will be in Paris soon and I was wondering if the Fibonacci Crocodile is still being displayed, or did I see a temporary exposition?

Answer (score 10):

Unlikely. The Crocodile was exhibited until [3rd February this year](http://www.konzerte-basel.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/documents/PressePDF/thibaudetBZ.pdf) in Basel, Switzerland. While there is a chance that it was immediately returned and exposed in Paris, I would not think so.

Answer (score 7):

First it seems the name of the piece of art is exactly "Crocodilus Fibonacci".

The museum has [a page](http://www.centrepompidou.fr/cpv/ressource.action;jsessionid=9E67CAB21F850FA801748F585B38A6F6?param.id=FR_R-c4efc2b631b0bda4bf4d9a1f237e7ad3&param.idSource=FR_O-e1f74ec133fd48464e73933bd765c57#) describing the piece of art. It belongs to the museum, so it might still be on display on the permanent collection floors. But I could not find any reference on the page saying it is actually the case.

Pictures on Flickr of this crocodile date from 2003 to 2008, so once again no assurance you will see it.